# using Iframe and allowing responsiveness

Tags: mobile, responsive

I have a link that if it goes to it directly, it is responsive, but if I put it in an iframe to "mask" the url, it is not responsive.

Is there a way to force allow it to be responsive?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example by Rik Flink @ http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/ that works nicely.  Change out the youtube url with getbootstrap.com (your own link may have origin issues depending upon your use of scripting) to see the responsive behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

```
<head>
 <title>Website Designs We Have Available to Start With</title>
 <META name="description" content="We can design your website with any of these layouts, and completely customize it to YOUR brand and Niche! It is FREE!!!">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://ibizleads.com/restaurant/" frameborder="0" />
 <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 10 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

So can you demo that and see what I'm talking about?
I didn't understand that jsfiddle and what you mean.
Sorry.